# cross platform local and push notification xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, notifications, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms,  local notifications and push notification  can be implemented in the cross platform  or is it a device specific feature in Xamarin forms .and how?

Comment: What have you researched so far

Comment: Till now I have encountered Nuget package suitable for local notification,but I have to implement push notification also,that too for the cross platform.

Comment: have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: I'm working on it, but I the progress is quiet slow in my case.

Comment: "local notifications and push notification can be implemented in the cross platform or is it a device specific feature in Xamarin forms" - What i can understand from this is, you've not done any study regarding how PushNotification works. Because xamarin forms has got nothing to do with it, as PNS are handled by different system in different platforms. Azure is still an abstract which points to different systems based on the platforms. I would suggest you to read a bit more about the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of down votes for the question though I shall give some leads on basis of how did I done this.
I used [Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin) which can get from [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.PushNotification). It can be used for Xamarin.Forms also but only support Android & iOs now.
For Android you will needed to configure [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) and for iOs you need to done with [APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html). You can refer below links for configuring Android & iOs with FCM & APNs respectively.

- [Refer this youtube video for Android FCM configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhKkLP2Z1Cc)
- [Refer this youtube video for iOS APNs configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg8baI2hkwM)

After that you will need to do some works on you project.
[Every steps are detailed on this link.](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md)

Don't forget to put some efforts on your queries before asking any question on SO.

Hope this will helps you. Happy Coding.